Can I use the same MTProto client library used in Telegram Web for my custom app?
I’m developing a custom Telegram app using React and I’d like to use the same MTProto client library that Telegram Web (https://web.telegram.org) uses. I know that Telegram Web directly communicates with Telegram’s MTProto servers without a middleman backend, and it must use a custom MTProto client for this purpose.
Here are my questions:
Is the MTProto client used in Telegram Web available as a standalone library?
If not, is there a way to extract or reuse the same MTProto client code from Telegram Web for my own project?
Are there any official alternatives provided by Telegram that work similarly to the Telegram Web client?
I want to avoid using third-party libraries like GramJS if possible, as I’m specifically looking for the library or implementation Telegram Web uses.
Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated!
